# getlistitem ignores list view filter

Tags: 2007, list-view, filter

Im using the webservice to get listitems from a list.  The list has a filter on it as well as an eventlistener.  The eventlistener triggers every time a new item is added to the list but it is possible that the newly added document won't show up in the filtered view.

In my request to getlistitems I specify the listname, the view name and use a query to retrieve the item using the items guid.  I would expect the query to return an empty resultset when the item doesnt exist in the list view, but unfortunately it appears that the view is ignored.

Interestingly enough if I run the getlistitems query without specifying the guid I want I only get the documents specific to the view.

is there a query option or something that I can use to make sure that the list items returned when specifying a guid adhere to the filter on the view?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the MSDN documentation for query parameter

*If supplied, the value of this parameter overrides either the query within the view specified by the viewName parameter or the query within the default view for the list.*

So the filter criteria defined in the view will be ignored here.

Comment: Are you aware of way to get an item but still maintain the list filter?  A shove in the right direction on where to look would be enough Im not totally lazy :)

Comment: I am not really sure if you can maintain the view filter restriction. But you can always design your query to maintain that restriction.